# (Kernel) developer-level documentation concerning OpenBSD

Tags: kernel, documentation, openbsd

OpenBSD is known to provide correct and extensive documentation, compared to e. g. GNU/Linux. Is there a technical overview, for a developer, who would like to start contributing code to OpenBSD? I usually mix with low-level aspects of OSes near HW. There is a Kernel Newbie program or a few books like Linux Device Drivers. Is there something similar available concerning OpenBSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there isn't similar books for OpenBSD. Mostly this information is shared in OpenBSD's handbooks, `man` pages and mailing lists. Definitely recommend reading into OpenBSD's `man` pages since they can offer great way to dive into for example system (`man 2`) and kernel calls (`man 9`).

Thankfully Stefan Sperling gave a great introductory speech couple of years ago on how to get started with OpenBSD kernel development, see slides at https://www.openbsd.org/papers/eurobsdcon2017-device-drivers.pdf and video itself at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W5qhWw07qpU.

Hopefully with these you can get started!

Comment: Hi! Thank you for reminding me the only resource I found when I had "I've got to get involved with OpenBSD kernel internals" stroke about a year ago - those slides!